# PlatformException throw unexpected

Tags: error-handling, dart, flutter, scoped-model

I call method in `ScopedModel` from outside `ScopedModel` (on button press). But `PlatformException` is not catch as I expect.

`PlatformException` is only catch in `ScopedModel` Method `try/catch`. It is not catch in button press `try/catch`.

**Button press:**

```
child: RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
try {
      await loginModel.signInWithGoogle();
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  debugPrint(e.toString());
}
  },
```

**ScopedModel Method:**

```
await _signInWithGoogle();

…

Future<void> _signInWithGoogle() async {


…
  throw PlatformException(code: ‘Test Exception’);
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  debugPrint(e.toString());
}
```

I throw `PlatformException` in `ScopedModel` to test when exception is throw from this method.

Why there is difference? I want catch `PlatformException` in button press

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried with `await loginModel.signInWithGoogle()` inside press button ?

Comment: @Hosar Thanks for reply! Is my error when I copy. I have `()` in code. Sorry! I have update example. Yes still have same issue.

Comment: As I'm understanding you are calling `signInWithGoogle` in the `loginModel` instance. But inside signInWithGoogle you have a try/catch. If you want to get the exception on pressButton you would need to remove the try/catch inside loginModel or **re-throw** the exception after this line: **debugPrint(e.toString())**

Comment: @Hosar Thanks for reply! Yes you understand correct. But even if I remove `try/catch` inside `loginModel`, the `try/catch` on button press is not catch `PlatformException`.

Comment: It should work, see a very simple example I posted. You can copy and paste, so you can see It will get into the **catch** block inside onPressed. Maybe in the process you are getting a different exception. Try removing **on PlatformException** and just keep **catch(e)**

Answer (score 0):

It should work. See a very simple example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Login userLogin = Login();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Simple exception test',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          try {
            await userLogin.signInWithGoogle();
          } on PlatformException catch (e) {
            print('Error ...:');
            print(e);
          }
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Login {
  Future<void> signInWithGoogle() async {
    throw PlatformException(code: 'Test Exception');
  }
}
```